# How to configure manual approval between terraform plan and apply while using Github environment

Tags: github

I'm using GitHub Environment to deploy into my testing account before merging to my master.I have specified the environment keyword in my workflow as "testing". My workflow will be triggered on a push to test branch which will then run plan and apply to testing account. I would like to have a manual approval after plan runs so I can see the output before approving to deploy into testing account. Please how can I configure manual approval so that after plan runs i can check the plan output before approving to deploy into my test account.

```
name: Testing Environment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test

jobs:
  plan&apply:
    name: "Run Terragrunt Init,Plan and Apply"
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    environment: testing

    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ env.TERRAFORM_WORKING_DIR }}
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout'
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1.3.2
        with:
          terraform_version: ${{ env.TERRAFORM_VERSION }}
          terraform_wrapper: true

      - name: Setup Terragrunt
        uses: autero1/action-terragrunt@v1.1.0
        with:
          terragrunt_version: ${{ env.TERRAGRUNT_VERSION }}

      - name: configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1.6.1
        with:
          aws-region: us-east-1
          role-to-assume: ${{ env.ORCHESTRATION_ROLE_ARN }}

      - name: Terragrunt Init
        id: init
        run: terragrunt run-all init -no-color --terragrunt-non-interactive

      - name: Terragrunt Plan
        id: plan
        run: |
          terragrunt run-all plan -no-color --terragrunt-non-interactive >/dev/null -out=tfplan

     - name: terragrunt Apply
       id: apply
       run : terragrunt run-all apply -no-color --terragrunt-non-interactive
       continue-on-error:true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

**Approach 1:**

In your GH actions environment settings, add reviewers. Create two jobs - Plan and Apply.  Then, add "needs" in apply job. This approach also requires to upload plan output as an artifact as plan and apply are two separate jobs.

```
name: Testing Environment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test

jobs:
  plan:
    name: "Run Terragrunt Plan"
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ env.TERRAFORM_WORKING_DIR }}
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout'
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1.3.2
        with:
          terraform_version: ${{ env.TERRAFORM_VERSION }}
          terraform_wrapper: true

      - name: Setup Terragrunt
        uses: autero1/action-terragrunt@v1.1.0
        with:
          terragrunt_version: ${{ env.TERRAGRUNT_VERSION }}

      - name: configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1.6.1
        with:
          aws-region: us-east-1
          role-to-assume: ${{ env.ORCHESTRATION_ROLE_ARN }}

      - name: Terragrunt Init
        id: init
        run: terragrunt run-all init -no-color --terragrunt-non-interactive
     - name: Create Artifact Folder 
       shell: bash
       run: |
          sudo mkdir -p -m777 ${{ github.workspace }}/tfplanoutput

      - name: Terragrunt Plan
        id: plan
        run: |
          terragrunt run-all plan -no-color --terragrunt-non-interactive >/dev/null -out=${{ github.workspace }}/tfplanoutput/tf.plan
      
      - name: Upload Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
         name: artifact
         path: ${{ github.workspace }}/tfplanoutput/
         if-no-files-found: error

apply:
    name: "Run Terragrunt Apply"
    needs: plan
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    environment: testing

      - name: 'Checkout'
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1.3.2
        with:
          terraform_version: ${{ env.TERRAFORM_VERSION }}
          terraform_wrapper: true

      - name: Setup Terragrunt
        uses: autero1/action-terragrunt@v1.1.0
        with:
          terragrunt_version: ${{ env.TERRAGRUNT_VERSION }}

      - name: configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1.6.1
        with:
          aws-region: us-east-1
          role-to-assume: ${{ env.ORCHESTRATION_ROLE_ARN }}

      - name: Terragrunt Init
        id: init
        run: terragrunt run-all init -no-color --terragrunt-non-interactive

     - name: Download Build Artifact
       uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
       with:
        name: artifact
        path: ${{ github.workspace }}/tfplanoutput

      - name: terragrunt Apply
        run : terragrunt run-all apply tf.plan -no-color --terragrunt-non-interactive 
        continue-on-error:true
```

**Approach 2:**
You can create composite actions - plan and apply same as above.

Hope this helps!!!